# Chrome: transform scale and blurred edges

Tags: css, google-chrome, webkit, transform

How remove blurred edges from blue div? http://jsfiddle.net/p4raT/

```
<div id="testContainer" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 1500px; height: 1500px; background: red; -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
-webkit-transform: scale(4.7);  ">      
<div id="testElement" style="position: absolute; left: 5px; top: 5px; width: 101px; height: 203px; background: blue;"><div> 
    <div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add `border: 1px solid blue;` to `#testElement` but that is dirty solution, because border will be scaled too and I'm not sure how that will affect other elements.

[See DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/p4raT/1/)

Better solution is to add any webkit filter. For example `-webkit-filter: blur(0px);`.

[See DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/p4raT/2/)

This is some rendering bug in Chrome (maybe in other browsers too, not tested) and adding filters simply fixes that. I don't know how but it works.

Comment: Filter makes no difference to me, still finding my borders are blurry due, I assume, to rounding issues. When I play with going from 50% to 51% by 0.1% steps, it seems to sharpen half way between. Really we need a "translate to nearest neighbour" type thing

Answer (score 0):

Recently I had same problem and found that solution that helped me

```
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialised;
```

or

```
backface-visibility: hidden;
```